# Querying a many to many relationship based on a value

Tags: node.js, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Currently I have a many-to-many relationship between entities. A Transaction contains many persons and a Person contains many Transactions. I'm writing a query to filter out transactions so that the transactions contains the person's name. The problem I'm running into is when I filter based on name, it removes the other Person from the transaction.

Example:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "txnDate": "2021-03-09T12:40:26.000Z",
        "persons": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Bill"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Jen"
            }
        ]
},
{
        "id": 2,
        "txnDate": "2021-03-09T12:40:26.000Z",
        "persons": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Jen"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Bob"
            }
        ]
},
```

My current query is:

```
query.leftJoinAndSelect('transaction.persons', 'persons')
     .andWhere('persons.name = :name', { name });
```

where `name` is a string. If I set `name= Bill` it results in:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "txnDate": "2021-03-09T12:40:26.000Z",
        "persons": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Bill"
            },
        ]
    },
```

However, I want it so that when I query by name it would result in:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "txnDate": "2021-03-09T12:40:26.000Z",
        "persons": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Bill"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Jen"
            }
        ]
    },
```

I'm really stuck and I would love any ideas on how to solve this

Current Stack: Nodejs, TypeORM, TypeScript